# How can I clear thread affinity with sched_setaffinity meaning I want to give control back to the kernel?

Tags: java, linux, kernel, real-time, jna

I looked everywhere but it appears that cannot be done. What I'm trying to avoid is:

*"A child created via fork(2) inherits its parent's CPU affinity mask."*

Source: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-dev/sched_setaffinity.2.en.html

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You added the `java` and `jna` tags, so are you trying to do this in Java?  What have you tried?  You can't "clear" it, you can only set it to something else, although it's possible to set it to "all available processors".  Did you keep track of what it was before you changed it the first time?

Comment: That was the answer! Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help. I reposted a more detailed version of that comment in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set affinity back to "all available processors."

One option might be to count up all your logical processors and use that bitmask, but it can be even easier, as [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity) includes these helpful remarks (emphasis mine):

> After a call to sched_setaffinity(), the set of CPUs on which the
>   process will actually run is **the intersection of the set specified in
>   the mask argument and the set of CPUs actually present on the system**.
>   The system may further restrict the set of CPUs on which the process
>   runs if the "cpuset" mechanism described in cpuset(7) is being used.
>   These restrictions on the actual set of CPUs on which the process will
>   run are silently imposed by the kernel.

So you can just send a bitmask of `0xffff...` which, conveniently, is the integer `-1`.  I'd suggest using a `long` value of -1, but if you know your system has fewer than 32 processors you could use an `int`.